# Stack Overflow UI Review Queues buttons shifted and hidden out of the screen

Tags: bug, review, design

This happens apparently because of scrolling and because the windows is wider than the whole content.

So, often the last button(s) (like Skip) not seen and unaccessible.
[image]

Comment: Are you at 100% zoom or have you zoomed in?

Comment: Repro... on 150% zoom...

Comment: Yes. I use 150% Windows scaling for my 1920 x 1080 13.3 inches display.

Comment: Also happens [without zoom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330496/can-we-skip-skipping-the-skip-button-please).  Open nearly one year already.  **:-(**