# Can we skip skipping the skip button, please?

Tags: bug, review, design

I never use my browser in full screen mode and when working the review queues, the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button <s>jumps off screen</s> is being skipped when I scroll down to see the comments as per screen record below:

[image: Skip button being skipped]

Can we please <s>stop this from happening</s> *skip skipping the skip button?*